# Need to create bins having equal population. Also need to generate a report that contains cross tab between bins and cut

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm using the diamonds dataset, below are the columns

[image]

Question: to create bins having equal population. Also need to generate a report that contains cross tab between bins and cut. Represent the number under each cell as a percentage of total

I have the above query. Although being a beginner, I created the Volume column and tried to create bins with equal population using qcut, but I'm not able to proceed further. Could someone help me out with the approach to solve the question?

```
pd.qcut(diamond['Volume'], q=4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right path: `pd.qcut()` attempts to break the data you provide into `q` equal-sized bins (though it may have to adjust a little, depending on the shape of your data).

`pd.qcut()` also lets you specify `labels=False` as an argument, which will give you back the number of the bin into which the observation falls. This is a little confusing, so here's a quick exaplanation: you could pass `labels=['A','B','C','D']` (given your request for 4 bins), which would return the labels of the bin into which each row falls. By telling `pd.qcut` that you don't have labels to give the bins, the function returns a bin number, just without a specific label. Otherwise, what the function gives back is a tuple with the range into which the observation (row) fell, and the bin number.

The reason you want the bin number is because of your next request: a cross-tab for the bin-indicator column and `cut`. First, create a column with the bin numbering:

`diamond['binned_volume`] = pd.qcut(diamond['Volume'], q=4, labels=False)`

Next, use the `pd.crosstab()` method to get your table:

`pd.crosstab(diamond['binned_volume'], diamond['cut'], normalize=True)`

The `normalize=True` argument will have the table calculate the entries as the entry divided by their sum, which is the last part of your question, I believe.